# In operating system, How MMU searches for virtual page number as key in page table

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, mmu

1)So lets say a single level page table
3)A TLB miss happens
3)The required page table is at main memory

 **Question** : Does MMU always fetch the page table required to a number of registers inside it so that fast hardware search like TLB can be performed? I guess no that would be costly hardware 
 
4)MMU fetch the physical page number (I guess MMU must be saved it with a format like high n-bits as virtual page no. and low m bits as physical page frame no. Please correct and explain if I am wrong)
 **Question**: I guess there has to be a key-value map with Virtual page no as key and physical frame no. as value. How MMU search for the key in the page table. If it is a s/w like linear search than it would be very costly.

5)With hardware it appends offset bits to page frame no.

and finally a read occurs for physical address.

So this question is bugging me a lot, how the MMU performs the search for given key(virtual page entry) in page table?

Comment: That would be totally architecture dependent, do you have a specific CPU/architecture in mind?

Answer (score 2):

> The use of registers for a page table is satisfactory if the page
> table is reasonably small(for example, 256 entries). Most contemporary
> computers, however, allow the page table to be very large (for
> example, 1 million entries). For these machines, the use of fast
> registers to implement the page table is not feasible. Rather, the
> page table is kept in main memory, and a **page table base register** (***PTBR***) points to the page table.
> Changing page tables requires changing only this one register,
> substantially reducing context-switch time.
>
> The problem with this
> approach is the time required to access a user memory location. If we
> want to access location ***i***, we must first index into the page table,
> using the value in the PTBR offset by the page number for ***i***. This task
> requires a memory access. It provides us with the frame number, which
> is combined with the page offset to produce the actual address. We can
> then access the desired place in memory. With this scheme, two memory
> accesses are needed to access a byte (one for the page-table entry,
> one for the byte). Thus, memory access is slowed by a factor of 2.
> This delay would be intolerable under most circumstances. We might as
> well resort to swapping!
>
> The standard solution to this problem is to
> use a special, small, fastlookup hardware cache, called a **translation look-aside buffer(TLB)** . The
> TLB is associative, high-speed memory. Each entry in the TLB consists
> of two parts: a key (or tag) and a value. When the associative memory
> is presented with an item, the item is compared with all keys
> simultaneously. If the item is found, the corresponding value field is
> returned. The search is fast; the hardware, however, is expensive.
> Typically, the number of entries in a TLB is small, often numbering
> between 64 and 1,024.

Source:**Operating System Concepts by Silberschatz et al. page 333**

Comment: Oh ya got it, it will have the base address at PTBR and the virtual memory address is contagious, so all it got to do is to is PTBR + virtual_memory_address/virtual_page_no to get the key and read the corresponding frame no. I find now the question was quite wrong and misleading, there is no need to search for a key in page table.  I don't know if I should delete the question. Thanks the explanation was gr8, really helped.

Comment: Welcome. You can edit your question in a way that is helpful to others.